# How to make center image bigger when scrolled vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many circle images in my page. When i scroll vertically, whatever the center image is in my page it should get zoomed like effect like as shown in the figure. I m not sure how to do this. So I m not posting any jsfiddle.

[image]

Comment: Can you just make a long image file file with the dots to get this effect? Or do you need to increase the size of a div as the user scrolls down?

Comment: to increase the size of the div as the user scrolls down. All the div's which comes exactly to the center increases their size gradually.

Comment: Some questions - is the page responsive? do the circles change with a transition? is the change in the dead center or a pixel amount from the bottom or top?

Comment: @NeilLittle yes, page is responsive. Circles remain same as circles. They grow in size when they r near to the center. They slowly become larger while the circle is getting center of the page and they become smaller when they move away from the center.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#spacer{height:1000px;}
#content{overflow-y:scroll;height:100%;width:100%;background:white;}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#fff">
<div id="content">

<div id="spacer"><!--other images --></div>

<img src="lock.png" class="images" id="firstimage"><br><br><img src="lock.png" class="images" id="secondimage"><br><br><img src="lock.png" class="images" id="thirdimage">

<div id="spacer"><!--other images --></div>

<span id="positionvalueboard" style="position:fixed;right:0px;top:0px;"><!--the position (from top) value (in %) to be displayed --></span>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
var repeataction= function() { 
var height=$(window).height(); /*WINDOW HEIGHT */
var position=$("#firstimage").position(); /*POSITION OF THE IMAGE */
var percent=position.top/height*100; /*CALCULATION OF PERCENTAGE */

$("#positionvalueboard").text(percent); /*CAN BE REMOVED IF NOT NEEDED */
$("#firstimage").height(percent*2); /* FOR THE 1st HALF ('*x' size increased x times) */

if(percent>50){$("#firstimage").height((100-percent)*2 )}; /* FOR THE 2nd HALF ('*x' size increased x times) */
};
var timeOut= setInterval(repeataction, 1); /* USED TO REPEAT THE ACTION */
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var repeataction= function() { 
var height=$(window).height(); /*WINDOW HEIGHT */
var position=$("#secondimage").position(); /*POSITION OF THE IMAGE */
var percent=position.top/height*100; /*CALCULATION OF PERCENTAGE */

$("#secondimage").height(percent*2); /* FOR THE 1st HALF ('*x' size increased x times) */

if(percent>50){$("#secondimage").height((100-percent)*2 )}; /* FOR THE 2nd HALF ('*x' size increased x times) */
};
var timeOut= setInterval(repeataction, 1); /* USED TO REPEAT THE ACTION */
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var repeataction= function() { 
var height=$(window).height(); /*WINDOW HEIGHT */
var position=$("#thirdimage").position(); /*POSITION OF THE IMAGE */
var percent=position.top/height*100; /*CALCULATION OF PERCENTAGE */

$("#thirdimage").height(percent*2); /* FOR THE 1st HALF ('*x' size increased x times) */

if(percent>50){$("#thirdimage").height((100-percent)*2 )}; /* FOR THE 2nd HALF ('*x' size increased x times) */
};
var timeOut= setInterval(repeataction, 1); /* USED TO REPEAT THE ACTION */
});
</script>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

THIS WILL WORK.

Comment: First try the code out without adding any other image (just replace lock.png). Also, for more images you need to multiply the jquery code.

Comment: Try it on you Mac/PC (by creating a new .html file) and not on jsfiddle or any other website, it's not working on jsfiddle.

Comment: Did you change 'js.js'  to any JQUERY src? I used the js.js while preparing this.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working here, I would check it out soon. :)

Comment: It's the file used to convert jquery into JavaScript which is then rendered by the browser, download it here: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Now, copy the code and again try it (if it didn't work), cause this time I added 2 more images and replace js.js (for convinience). :)

Comment: It wont work on jsfiddle, I dont know why its not working for you (on your PC). Update your browser (or change it). It works on Chrome, just like it worked in that video.

Comment: i m checking in all browsers ie, firefox, chrome. i m working on new html page. do u want me to mail the code? my chrome is updated one. i think problem is with js. i tried in mac system also.